# Send Details via sms

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, sms, windows-phone-7.1

Detail page:

```
// When page is navigated to set data context to selected item in list
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedIndex = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
    {
        int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
        DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
    }
}
```

is it possible to send details content that are stored in DataContext as a sms?

Comment: I would be extremely concerned if you could send an SMS via the phone without the user knowing..

Comment: (snide mode on) being windows phone 7 I sincerely doubt you can do it with their permission either. :-) (snide mode off)

Answer (score -1):

May be it will help you: http://www.ginktage.com/2011/03/how-to-send-sms-in-windows-phone-7-using-c/

Set “Body” property to a text with details content.

Comment: i cannot understand what you keep in mind about the 'details content'